# Zend_Http_UserAgent to detect Mobile Browsers

Tags: php, zend-framework

Im trying to do some mobile detection and this module is giving me problems.

```
$config = array('storage' => array('adapter' => 'Zend_Http_UserAgent_Storage_Session'));
    try
    {
        //$bootstrap = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');
        //$userAgent = $bootstrap->getResource('useragent');
        //Bootstrap::pr($userAgent);
        //echo $userAgent->getUserAgent();
        $ua = new Zend_Http_UserAgent($config);
        Bootstrap::pr($ua);
        Bootstrap::pr($ua->getDevice());


    }catch(Exception $e)
    {
        Bootstrap::pr($e);
    }
```

This is within the index action of my index controller.

Bootstrap::pr is basically a print_r wrapped with `<pre>`'s

when i open the page, the print_r for $ua works, but then it just dies and the page is blank. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: When you say "the page is blank", you mean the *rest* of the page, right? Can you paste the `Bootstrap::pr()` method? Off topic but you can use `Zend_Debug::dump()` instead of rolling your own

Comment: figured it out, apparently the version of zend i was using didnt have the UserAgent stuff in it yet, just upgraded and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Zend_Http_UserAgent` depends on `WURFL` library, you have to configure it as described in [the manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.user-agent.html).

Comment: it was, turned out to be an include problem with zend

Answer (score 0):

Check out WURFL - it may be just what you are looking for.